# Tried to remove files from git, now branches are diverged and I can't push the changes

Tags: git, gitignore, git-push, git-commit, git-filter-branch

This is the first time for me using git (on bitbucket.org - if that makes any difference) and I committed a few audio files to the repo which I obviously don't want there. I added then added the paths to the .gitignore to find out that this will only ignore further changes.
So I stumbled upon [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history) and tried to use [David Underhill's script](http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/) that's mentioned there.

However, now I'm getting the following message for `git commit`:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 10 and 10 different commits each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

and for `git push`

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/abc/def'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I tried a `git push --force` which succeeded but didn't actually change anything in the repo and doesn't even show up there.

Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: that is strange. Do git push -f and git status and post all the output please

Answer (score 1):

A `git filter-branch` will rewrite the history of SHA1 of your commits, so the error message makes sense.

If your local repo is on branch master and have those files removes, then `git push -f` will mirror that on your bitbucket repo.

If it doesn't, it maybe because you are not pushing local master in the first place (try `git push -f origin master` to be sure).
Ir because you are (locally) in a [detached head mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).